# Why do I get low FPS while gaming?

Tags: nvidia, games, performance, bumblebee, framerate

I just updated to Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows 10. I liked it a lot but the thing is that i get low fps while gaming.
ex. CS:GO
win10 = 200
ubuntu = 15-20

Why is this happening? I tried to download nvidia-drivers, bumblebee but bumblebee gave errors about sockets. Please help!

System info:

```
-Processors-

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz        : 499.99MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz        : 499.99MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz        : 499.79MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz        : 499.99MHz

-PCI Devices-

Host bridge     : Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)

VGA compatible controller       : Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

USB controller      : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])

Communication controller        : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)

SATA controller     : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])

PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

ISA bridge      : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)

Memory controller       : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)

Audio device        : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

SMBus       : Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)

3D controller       : NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930M] (rev a2)

Network controller      : Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)

Ethernet controller     : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 

RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

I tried to install nvidia-367 driver.

Comment: Please edit and post your hardware specs and what drivers you tried to install.

Comment: Yeah, I did that.

Comment: 1.  *Skylake* CPU: I'm not sure if applicable still but at one time it required some additional Grub parameters ; 2. `nvidia-367` should work and, when installed with system settings, it should pull `nvidia-prime` (not `bumblebee`, no longer recommended for newer chipsets, I think). `ǸVIDIA X Server Settings` is where users toggle graphics Intel/Nvidia)

Comment: Considering the above, you were probably using Intel Graphics at the time.   The Nvidia one should give much higher FPS but it may not be as high as in Windows with DirectX, the proprietary technology for which the game was written, OpenGL was an afterthought.

Comment: I tried Nvidia X Settings but there is nowhere that i can change the GPU. ;_;

Comment: I figured a way to use nvidia gpu but now when i try to open something it says "Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual". how can i solve that